# Run-time compilation with Roslyn - How to produce AoT compilation

Tags: c#, runtime, .net-5, ahead-of-time-compile

I have been exploring run-time dynamic code compilation using c# with Roslyn. Using this answer on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60042367/dynamically-compile-and-run-code-using-net-core-3-0-for-scripting) I have been able to complete an example that does what I want with the exception of one thing: It produces a dll which must then be invoked with the `dotnet` command. I conclude from what I have googled thus far that it is possible to AoT with .NET 5 at this point and produce an .exe that is self contained. Based on `CSharpCompilation` could someone direct me to a good example of how to do this?